# sqlite: no column after alter table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to add column to existing table, and then use it:

```
sqlite> create table tst(id_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, s1 TEXT);    
sqlite> .tables
tst
sqlite> insert into tst (s1) values ("AA");
sqlite> select * from tst;
1|AA
sqlite> alter table tst add colum s2 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "BB";
sqlite> select * from tst;
1|AA|BB
sqlite> .schema tst
CREATE TABLE tst(id_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, s1 TEXT, colum s2 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "BB");
```

So all looks fine.

But

```
sqlite> select s2 from tst;
Error: no such column: s2
```

So in scheme there is "s2" column,
sole record contains data in "s2" field,
but sqlite don't know column s2.

What is wrong, I used "alter table" in wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column is not named `s2`, but `colum`. Check your `ALTER TABLE` for spelling.

```
sqlite> select colum from tst;
BB
```

This question should probably be closed, as it is about a typo.

---

BTW, code should be formatted with four spaces in front, not as a text quote; this gives you monospace font and syntax highlighting; the latter might have helped you see the problem ^^

Comment: Thanks, actually my real problem was that sqlite not support multiply columns in "altere table add", and I try reproduce this error with more simple environment then my application, but looks like I need go to sleep.